# Edge selection behavior, how to make it like Maya?

Tags: modeling, edges, selection-tools

The Image clearly describes my problem with Blender, how can I change this to work like it does in maya? I have looked extensively in preferences, and I can't find anything.

I want box select to select all edge it touches, like it does in maya, Instead in Blender, only edges that are completely inside the box get selected
[image]

Comment: Do you _need_) to use box select? If you want the whole "side of edges" selected, just hold Alt and click the edge. If you already have edges selected that you want too stay selected, use Shift+Alt+Click.

Comment: I want box select to select all edge it touches, like id does in maya, Instead in Blender, only edges that are completely inside the box get selected.

Comment: Try pressing C, and scrolling the mouse to increase/decrease the selection size. It will select anything the circle touches when you click. Not quite the same as box, but it still handles multiple selections.

Comment: Recommend [edit] prior [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234703/edge-selection-behavior-how-to-make-it-like-maya#comment397726_234703) into question.

Comment: as Christopher says, it looks like edge loop (except it's not the same)

Comment: This is  absolutely true. Box edge-select does not fulfil the promise made in the manual: "Any item that lies even partially within this rectangle becomes selected." It is also inconsistent. Get-around: use 'C' circle select for non-colinear selections. Is this a reportable bug? Variants of the problem seem fairly common in the task-list already..

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was some inconsistency too, but I couldn't quite capture it!
At least I can rest somewhat knowing that the functionality isn't there at all. It would be great if this was toggleable feature

Comment: @Mikael as it happens, I find this 'error'  convenient, to the extent I hadn't noticed it until you raised the issue.  Personally, when I (rarely) use  box-select for edges, it _is_ to select  aligned elements, not in a loop, If I want cross-members, too, I  use C.